# Which is the proper grammatical structure of page titles?

Tags: copywriting, grammar, page-title

We have a pages that are labeled inconsistently and I suggested that we use more affirmative syntax.

"Manage Audiences" is a page title which reads poorly and doesn't sound right. "Audiences," is particularly awkward.

My suggestion is "Audience Management."

I forget exactly why the later is a more accurate representation. Does the later example reduce syntactic ambiguity?

Our current naming convention does not use actions to describe pages. 
Other pages include

Reporting

Trends

Campaign Overview

Customer Inventory

Templates

Email Blasts

Account Setup

CTAs have labels such as…

Open Audience

Save Audience

New Email Blast

New Campaign

Apply Selection

The way I've often approached this is by adding the phrase "Welcome to…"
 when speaking the page view aloud.

> e.g. "Welcome to… Manage Audiences" versus "Welcome to… Audience Management."

Additionally, when writing button-label copy, I prefer to phrase it as a statement or directive.

> e.g. "I want… a new campaign" or "I would like to… add a user."

This helps with story telling and maintains a coherent dialog with the user. This is my approach to this solution, yet I seem to be getting some push back from the stakeholders with no real reason besides "I liked it the other way."

[Insert something about UX story telling and conversational UI/IxD]

*Edit*

Adding some more context

Comment: This is more content strategy than UX - In the absence of a Content Strategy stackexchange you might want to try https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it's difficult to say what labels are most appropriate. Often, the most accurate or descriptive term won't be the best label, because of what users are accustomed to.

I would recommend doing a [card sorting exercise](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/card-sorting-terminology-matches/) in order to see what makes the most sense for your users.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct for consistency is good... Some other things to take into account in nomenclature:

Is your audience the "home user" or admin types - will they appreciate, or be distracted by, a "friendlier" locution rather than a passive and techy one?

Is the user going to perform a task (for which an active phrasing such as "Manage Audiences" would be better) or just view information?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer--can you expand upon your thoughts and provide some references to support your argument?